# Floor divison operator applied to a list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, arithmetic-expressions, floor-division

```
def median(numbers):
    numbers.sort() 
    if len(numbers) % 2:
        # if the list has an odd number of elements,
        # the median is the middle element
        middle_index = int(len(numbers)/2)
        return numbers[middle_index]
    else:
        # if the list has an even number of elements,
        # the median is the average of the middle two elements
        right_of_middle = len(numbers)//2 
        left_of_middle = right_of_middle - 1
        return (numbers[right_of_middle] + numbers[left_of_middle])/2
```

## Examples of results:

```
>>> x=[5,10,15,20]
>>> median(x)
12.5
>>> x=[17,4,6,12]
>>> median(x)
9.0
>>> x=[13,6,8,14]
>>> median(x)
10.5
```

I have run this function and it works fine. At the beginning it was diffilcult to understand the results but finally I got it!.

However, I do not understand why only the first result is like it is intended to be. I mean the result is the average of the two middle numbers of the list.

I hope you understand I am learning on my own and sometimes it is not easy.

Comment: I do not understand what are you asking here. The result are correct in all three cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function works only in the first example because only the first list is sorted. Sort the other list or sort within the function.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because of that line:

```
numbers.sort()
```

so, `[17,4,6,12]` becomes `[4,6,12,17]` which his median is `9`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably asking:

> Why is the median *different* from the mean?

The answer is then this:

> The median is the value separating the higher half of a data sample, a population, or a probability distribution, from the lower half.

(From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median).)

> For a data set, the terms arithmetic mean, mathematical expectation, and sometimes average are used synonymously to refer to a central value of a discrete set of numbers: specifically, the sum of the values divided by the number of values.

(From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean).)

Those two values may be equal but *in general there are different*:

If you have *10 poor people* and a *1 millionaire*, the *mean* will be *very high*, but the median (the salary of the *6th* most poor person) will be *still very low*.